# What is the proper code for Realm inverse connection?

Tags: swift, realm

Realm demo database has sample objects with inverse connection: objectReference has a link to RealmTestClass1.

```
class RealmTestClass1: Object {
  dynamic var integerValue = 0
  let arrayReference = List<RealmTestClass0>()
}

class RealmTestClass2: Object {
  dynamic var boolValue = false
  dynamic var objectReference: RealmTestClass1?
}
```

How to re-create that same structure? What code is needed for objectReference property to create that same link to parent object property?

Answer (score 0):

Links in Realm are *unidirectional*. So if a to-many property Person.dogs links to a Dog instance and a to-one property Dog.owner links to Person, these links are independent from one another. Appending a Dog to a Person instance’s dogs property, doesn’t automatically set the dog’s owner property to this Person. Because manually synchronizing pairs of relationships is error prone, complex and duplicates information, Realm exposes an API to retrieve backlinks described below.

With inverse relationships, you can obtain all objects linking to a given object through a specific property. For example, calling [`Object.linkingObjects(_:forProperty:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift6Object14linkingObjectsFS0_U__FTMQ_11forPropertySS_GSaQ__) on a Dog instance will return all objects of the specified class linking to the calling instance with the specified property. It’s possible to simplify this pattern by defining a read-only (computed) owners property on Dog:

```
class Person: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    var owners: [Person] {
        // Realm doesn't persist this property because it only has a getter defined
        // Define "owners" as the inverse relationship to Person.dogs
        return linkingObjects(Person.self, forProperty: "dogs")
    }
}
```

This was taken from [Realm's docs on relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships), which I encourage you to read.

Comment: thank so much for reply. i read the docs on realm. yet sometimes reading doesn't make it more clear. the code you cited doesn't add new column with the link to person as it is in demo database.

Comment: I suppose I don't really understand your question then. "How to re-create that same structure?" the code you posted seems to have the structure you describe, no? How's it different from what you want to accomplish? " What code is needed for objectReference property to create that same link to parent object property?" Two separate link properties can't share the same link, that's what I mean by "links are unidirectional". If you want to just set *one* link, you should use `linkingObjects(_:forProperty:)` as written in my answer above.

Comment: i'm sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. let me give another try. please see the [screenshot](https://s13.postimg.org/5bkv8zunr/111.jpg). i'm trying to achieve the same link connection as it it in Realm demo database.

Comment: In the top part of your image, there are links from `Person` to `Dog` via the `Person.dogs` relationship property. To get "incoming" links to a given `dog` object instance, you can use the `Dog.linkingObjects(Person.self, forProperty: "dogs")` function included in my answer above. To create additional links from `Dog` to `Person`, you could add a stored owners property to `Dog`: `let owners = List<Person>()` and do some double bookkeeping to explicitly set the inverse whenever you set `Person.dogs`.